# Remove minimum value from linkedlist

Tags: java, data-structures

I need to remove the smallest element value from the linked list. Like

```
{8,4,7,2,9,4,5,3}
```

Becomes:

```
{8,4,7,9,4,5,3}
```

I wrote this :

```
public void RemoveMin() {
    T min = list.getInfo();
    for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
        if (list.getLink() < min)
            min = (T) list.getLink();
        else
            continue;
    }
}
```

Comment: *"Remove minimum value from linkedlist?"*  Is a statement with an ending of '?' as opposed to a question.  What *is* your question?

Comment: what is the question here ?

Comment: `list.getLink() < min` If `min` is a `T`, how can `min` be compared?

Comment: my method is removemin () is linked list and i need to remove the minimue in linked list , thats my question

Comment: What if min occurs more than once?

Comment: That's not a question. A question ends with a question mark.

Comment: '        else
            continue;
' is pointless

Comment: i need just for one time as you can see . example then i will understand

Comment: There seem to be several problems with your code. For example: What does `getLink()` do? You are calling it twice, but it seems that you are using it to also iterate over the list. I think you could help us with showing the code for `getInfo()` and `getLink()`.

Comment: traverse the whole list to find the  min (your for loop is unusual), then find the node previous to the one with the min value(special case is if min is at the head of the list), then previous.link = previous.next.link will delete the node with the minimum value.

Comment: traverse the whole list to find the  min (your for loop is unusual), maintain a node to the node previous to the one with  the minimum (updating it as necessary - special case is if min is at the head of the list), then previous.link = previous.next.link will delete the node with the minimum value. All in one pass.

Answer (score 3):

You can do like this :

```
public void RemoveMin()
{
   int nbElements = list.size()
   int lowerValueIndex = 0
   for (i = 0; i < nbElements; i++)
   {
      if(list.get(i) < list.get(lowerValueIndex)
      {
         lowerValueIndex = i;
      }
   }
   list.remove(lowerValueIndex);
}
```

First you initializethe lowest value with the first element.
Then at each element, you compare the value with the lower one who is already find.
if the new is lower, you take the new lowerValueIndex.
At the end you just have to remove the lowest element founded.
Be carefull, with this solution, your data must be comparable directly

Comment: This solution is good if the List contains elements which can be compared the the "<" operator. In other cases a special comparator is needed.

Comment: I think `list.get(i).compareTo(list.get(lowerValueIndex)) < 0` is better.

Comment: If the list has a "min", the elements should be part of an ordered set and have < > operators.

Comment: Oh right java doesn't have operator overloading.

Comment: You shouldn't need size(), that implies traversing the whole list agin (which was already done to find out min.

Comment: yes sure – user2151446 use a foreach is better, just I have a doubt about the iterator if he's already in a foreach or if he use the iterator on this object when he use the fonction

Comment: @user2151446 In `java.util.LinkedList` of my JVM, `getSize()` just return `size`, it doesn't traverse the whole list.

Comment: @johnchen902 fair enough.

Answer (score 0):

If your question is how to remove the minimum Element of a list where the elements are of a generic type T, then you should do the following:

1. you need to have a comparator by which you can compare the elements
   to find the minimum
2. you have to iterate over the list to find that minimum element
3. you have to remove this element from the list.

Comment: If your list only contains ints, then you can simply choose the code from the answer of daarksim.